# Dotnet 8 Datetime without timezone

Tags: .net, postgresql, datetime, timezone

We upgraded our solution from DotNet 6 to DotNet 8. Our database is on PostgreSQL. We keep datetime values as datetime without timezone. In DotNet 6 version, we receive datetime values from backend as it is saved, such as 2024-02-11T14:00:00.0000000. That shows in front end as same as is. However DotNet 8 version ads a Z, 2023-10-25T11:05:00.0000000Z which indicates timezone and in front end it causes timezone calculation. How can I disable that and get back to receiving dates without timezone?

Comment: No, .NET doesn't do that. DateTime is a binary value, it has no format and hasn't changed in 20+ years. A `DateTime` object always had a `Kind` property that can be Local, UTC or Unspecified. `from backend as it is saved` saved where and how? In what field, what type? Post your code and table schema

Comment: Are you sure the the change wasn't in the servers? PostgreSQL's [TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT-TIME-STAMPS) always stores values as UTC. The actual offset is lost. When you read that value back, it's converted to the "current timezone", whether that's specified as a server setting or a driver setting. It seems the "current timezone" in either the database or application server is UTC. By default, cloud providers create VMs and services in the UTC timezone.

Comment: When I retrieve values from the database, dates are as same as in the db. So Entity Framework works as I expected. I have checked the object just before 
return Ok(theList) and datetime value is for example "2023-11-19T14:24:53", but what I get from the json data from Ok, it returns 2023-11-19T14:24:53.751144Z

Comment: It turned out that problem is not the serialization, but the kind of datetime when I retrieve from the database. On Dotnet6 version we receive datetime values with Unspecified kind, but now with Dotnet 8 UTC. How can I set the default kind to Unspecified upon reading the values?

Comment: @OzkanTuzemen - The value being set to `DateTimeKind.Utc` on retrieval could indeed explain your results, but nothing in .NET itself has changed in this regard.  It's possible the change is in a particular component, such as EF Core, Npgsql's EF Core Provider, Npgsql itself, or more likely, in your own code or database.  You'll need to show us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that has this behavior to troubleshoot further.  Thanks.